# make animation like braking image

Tags: android, animation

I want to make animation like braking image. I made anim folder and made anim file but not working like spreading,can any one tell me how can i make it?
Is it posible to make spread animation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: means image opening with small parts of image and then show big image....now understand.,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the way you want to go, but using vector graphics would certainly fulfill your needs.

The upside is that you have absolute control over the drawing.

The downside is you have to write the graphics algorithms yourself.

Basic tutorials:
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-canvas-your-android-apps-part-1
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-canvas-your-android-apps-part-2
https://web.archive.org/web/20201026064852/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/06/drawing-with-canvas-in-android.html